# Javascript date picker MooTools

Tags: javascript, css, datepicker, mootools

I'm trying to get the following demo script working http://www.monkeyphysics.com/mootools/script/2/

Here is the code I have:

```
<style type="text/css">
// this code http://www.monkeyphysics.com/mootools/fetch/4/datepicker.css
</style>
<script src="datepicker.js"></script>  //tested in browser, correct path

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.addEvent('load', function() {
new DatePicker('.demo_vista', { pickerClass: 'datepicker_vista' });
new DatePicker('.demo_dashboard', { pickerClass: 'datepicker_dashboard' });
new DatePicker('.demo_jqui', { pickerClass: 'datepicker_jqui', positionOffset:        { x: 0, y: 5 } });
new DatePicker('.demo', { positionOffset: { x: 0, y: 5 }});
});</script>

<label>Datepicker with Vista skin:</label>
<input name='date_B' type='text' value='' class='date demo_vista' />

<label>Datepicker with OSX Dashboard skin:</label>
<input name='date_B' type='text' value='' class='date demo_dashboard' />

<label>Datepicker with jQuery UI skin:</label>
<input name='date_B' type='text' value='' class='date demo_jqui' />

<label>Datepicker basic (CSS only):</label>
<input name='date_B' type='text' value='' class='date demo' />
```

This is the exact copy / paste from the site, and the the issue I get is no loading of the date picker, at all. It's like it's not finding the JS file (tested path in browser, it is), can anyone see an issue?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work for me in IE10 (but does in Chrome). Which browser(s) are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tested in FF and Opera without luck.

Comment: That script you are using might not work with modern releases of MooTools, you could try using https://github.com/arian/mootools-datepicker/ which is a continuation of that project (many bugs fixed, some new features)